# QPrinter не видит подключенные к компьютеру принтеры

Tags: c++, qt5

Проблема в том, что QPrinter не находит подключённые к компьютеру принтеры, хотя они 100% есть. На моём компьютере всё нормально работает, собираю дистрибутив и ставлю на другой комп - не работает. В чём причина? Как решить проблему? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Плагин windowsprintersupport тоже поставляете с приложением?

Comment: Да, тоже. Спасибо, что навели на мысль. Эту dll нужно было положить не просто рядом с exe, а в папку printsupport. Буду знать теперь, учусь на ошибках.